# Beaglebone Black SPI and GPIO

Tags: python, beagleboneblack, gpio, spi

Good Day,

I have a project on the beaglebone black that needs to use SPI and GPIO my problem is I can't seem to use GPIO as an input when I try to use the BB-SPIDEV0-00A0 overlay. I tried and tried using different spi overlays with exclusive use pins and ends up the board not booting properly and recovered the uEnv.txt the nth time, I think I have problems with my pinmux and want to know what am I missing. I'm using the lastest debian image form BBB. I'm using python for this project.

Thanks.

Comment: People will be better able to help if you post the relevant code.

Comment: You should be able to set up your pinmux at runtime without the need of overlays on a recent image. This is achieved using `config-pin`.